# Why is my Bootstrap table overflowing the containing card?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Actually i'm trying to set a table inside a bootstrap card, the issue is that the table width goes out off that card and i would to prevent it.
The table is made for each tr of one th and 96 td.

[image]

I was trying to set the table width to 100% and set to each td 1% of width but i didn't worked

[image]

Here is the table code:

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card p-2">
                            <div class="card-body text-center" >
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <tbody>
                                          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please show rendered markup, not server-side template code. Bootstrap doesn't care about the latter, and neither do we in this case.

Comment: @isherwood http://jsfiddle.net/mgaryh1p/ in the fiddle is shown fine, i found that if i cancel the "table" class from table tag the table will fit perfectly in the card, the reason is that i'm going to make a "timeline" on that table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the padding that Bootstrap applies. It results in each cell having a minimum width of 24px.

```
.table.no-cellpadding td
  padding: 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/z2dsro9m/4)**

Comment: Amazing-I added `padding: 0` to the `card-body` class and it worked. But why doesn't `table-responsive` reduce the padding proportionally?

Comment: You'll have to ask the Bootstrap developers. My guess is that they didn't want to get ham-handed with something that's used in such a wide variety of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wrapping each set of td tags with a tr?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card p-2">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="class">

                            </tr>
                            <tr class="class">

                            </tr>
                            <tr class="class">

                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = () => {
            let allTrs = document.querySelectorAll('tr.class');

            allTrs.forEach((tr) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < 96; i++) {
                    const newTd = document.createElement('td');
                    newTd.style = "width: 1%";
                    newTd.appendChild(document.createTextNode('value'))
                    tr.appendChild(newTd)
                }
            })
        }

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Does this fit your needs?

Comment: yes i do, each row is made as following "<tr><th></th><td></td><td></td>...x96</tr>

Comment: Trying using this:  <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">33</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

Comment: actually i need these 96 <td> so i have to use them

Comment: If you want 96 rows, use something like this for each row. These are two rows: <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Hello</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                    <td>Hello</td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>

Comment: i doesnt need 96 rows but columns in it. as you can see on the screen all is right but just the table is going out of card

Comment: Are you not trying to achieve what you have in the first picture?

Comment: yes i do but as you can see it's width is going off of the card as there are 96 td, so i would be able to resize it and let it fit in the card

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you want now. Use <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 1%">H</td>
                                <td style="width: 1%">H</td>
                                <td style="width: 1%">H</td>
                                <td style="width: 1%">H</td>
                                <td style="width: 1%">H</td></tr></tbody>

Comment: Evan, as you can see on the second screen it's what i've yet tryed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here. Do you want 96 rows? Or do you want 96 columns in 1 row?

Comment: I want 96 columns in 1 row and i have yet them but the problem is that they doesn't fit inside the bootstrap card