# How can I reference a table cell by its position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row in a table with the head of the row and 96 cells.

Each row is clickable by the following function

```
$("#table tr").click(function(){});
```

Now by getting value from 0 to 96, I need to get the `td` in the place X and do a `colspan` on it.

As in the form, I get value 40 I need to make the `colspan` on the 40th `td` in the clicked row.

How can I implement something like that in JavaScript or jQuery?

**Thank's to Pete comment** I've got how to get `td` to which change the attribute, the problem now is if I `colspan` the cell the table become deformed as on the screen

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using $(this)? It's not clear what you have and haven't tried yet.

Comment: have a look at `$(this).find('td').eq(39)` - https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Please post your markup (or a simplified sample). Where does the value come from?

Comment: @isherwood updated

Comment: @JohnKarry think you need to remind yourself of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - we cannot properly help you if you do not create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.  The only code you have shown has nothing to do with your problem as you have said the things are coming from inputs.  But to solve your colspan problem, I would do a loop from 1 to colspan and remove the next cell after the td you put the colspan on

Comment: To balance the `colspan` attribute's effects you'd have to eliminate that quantity of cells from the row. As I mentioned in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302561/table-out-of-bootstrap-card/55303961#55303961), a table probably isn't your best approach to layout for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. You need to add colspan attribute first and then need to remove last cells as below:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){            
                $("#tables tr").click(function() {
                    let position = 2;
                    let colspan = 2;

                    $(`td:eq(${position-1})`, this).prop('colspan', colspan);
                    $(`td:eq(${position+colspan})`, this).nextAll().remove();

                });
            });
```

Hope it helps you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery selector `:eq()` to get the position you want with the `prop()` method that will set the `colspan` attribute, like :

```js
$("#table tr").click(function() {
  let position = 5;
  let colspan = 2;

  $(`td:eq(${position-1})`, this).prop('colspan', colspan);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```